# Verifying that a file is ready for reading in py3k

Tags: python, file-io

I'm writing to a file for another program (gnuplot) to use as input.

```
g = open('test.gnuplot', 'w')
g.write("[snip]")
g.close()

os.system("sleep 1")
os.system("gnuplot test.gnuplot")
```

If I omit the `sleep 1` gnuplot generates a mangled file - seemingly because the file I just wrote isn't "ready" yet (if I'm wrong please tell me what the real reason is).

I'm guessing there is a more elegant way to wait for the file to be ready for reading, what is it?

Comment: Try switching off your anti-virus software and seeing if the sleep can be removed

Comment: Presumably you're waiting to do the actual writing, what happens if you call `g.flush()` before `g.close()`? Can you take the `sleep` out then? And BTW you can say `import time; time.sleep(`)` in Python.

Comment: Try this: `g.write("[snip]"); g.flush(); os.fsync(g.fileno())` And take away the `os.system("sleep 1")`. I may be wrong but I think the buffer is not yet written to the file. See: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fsync

Comment: The select library might be of some help http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#select.select

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what does the anti-virus gotta do with the file problem?

Comment: @jason It locks the file to perform checking. Depends on the scanner.

Comment: @jason fsync is just going to hurt performance by flushing disk cache to the disk. Rather pointless. RAM is much faster than disk.

Comment: TWhat O.S. are you  on? If you are on Windows, and running an antiirus, yes, that is indeed the cause. If you are ona Posix (Mac OS or Linuyx) system, what you are getting is really weird.

Comment: Even if you need to sleep for a second, why in the world would you shell out to do it?

Comment: @kindall : It was quicker - I was just prototyping. I'm aware that python has the capability, but I just wanted to test it quickly (since I suspected it was a buffer issue that could be hacked to work by not going "too fast").

Comment: @JasonYeo : Your comment is correct and the most thorough. Would you copy it into an answer so I can accept it? Otherwise in a couple of days I will do so and mark it as community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
g = open('test.gnuplot', 'w')
g.write("[snip]")
g.flush()
os.fsync(g.fileno()) 
os.system("gnuplot test.gnuplot")
```

And take away the `os.system("sleep 1")`. I think the buffer is not yet written to the file. See the python [fsync docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fsync).